# Strange result for same xpath query between scrapy shell and spider. Why?

Tags: scrapy

Please forgive my noob questions as I am a scrapy beginner.

I'm running into a strange difference between the scrapy shell and my spider with the same xpath query. The spider is set up to follow the "Next" page link and then parse the results.

The query:

```
response.xpath('//div/div/span/a[starts-with(.,"Next")]/@href')
```

Spider Code:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mich"
    allowed_domains = ["lib-web.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('p/text()').extract()

            yield item

        next_page = response.xpath('//div/div/span/a[starts-with(.,"Next")]/@href')
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
            print "#################################################################"
            print url
            print "#################################################################"
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

DmozItem:

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

When I run the query in the shell, it **doesn't** actually show the href for the next page, which should include "/page-2.html" (starting from the start_urls):

```
Admin$ scrapy shell "http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/"
...
In [1]: response.xpath('//div/div/span/a[starts-with(.,"Next")]/@href')
Out[1]: [<Selector xpath='//div/div/span/a[starts-with(.,"Next")]/@href' 
data=u'/united-states/public-libraries/michigan'>]
```

But, the spider, with this exact query **does** find the correct href for the Next page (/page-2.html). The full Next page href looks like this:

```
http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/page-2.html
```

Which is not at all what the shell showed.

So how did the spider actually work? How is the spider getting the next page, when the shell query is not showing it?

By the way, if I add ".extract()" to the shell query, it does now show the next page URL, which is what I wanted to see:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//div/div/span/a[starts-with(.,"Next")]/@href').extract()
Out[1]: [u'/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/page-2.html']
```

But if I use ".extract()" with the spider, it breaks with the following error:

```
 url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I just answered this myself. As usual, it's good to pay attention to error messages.

In the shell query, I didn't use .extract(), which is why I didn't see the URL I wanted. The spider actually functioned properly with the same query because I did the .extract() when I did the urljoin:

```
url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
```

So, the .extract() does need to happen. It can be either in the urljoin or in the prior response.xpath query.